# Onclick update database in Codeigniter using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to update in database when I click a button in my View file.

VIEW

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($leavelist->result() as $key){
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$key->emp_id.'</td>
    <td>'.$key->status.'</td>
    <td><a id="a'.$key->emp_id.'" onclick="Approved(\''.$key->id.'\')" title="Approve" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" success><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></td>
    </tr>';
    }
?> 
</tbody>


<script>
function Approved(id){

    butId = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo $this->config->item("index_url")."Admin/ApproveLeave";?>",
          data: { "rowid": butId },
          dataType:"text",
          success:function(data){
              alert(data);
          },
          error:function (data){
              alert("failed");
          }
        });

}
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function ApproveLeave(){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('general_model','gm');
        $inputdata=array('status'=>'Approved');
        $params=array('table_name'=>'leave_application','primary_key'=>'id');
        $this->gm->initialize($params);
        $this->gm->updateEntry($_POST['rowid'],$inputdata); 
    }
```

Above is my AJAX and controller code. When I click the button it shows Undefined index. Can anyone help me where I'm wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `butId ` in `Approved()` function?

Comment: No, I'm not.Can it be modified it into something else?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I think you are not getting `butId` properly.

Try this:

```
 <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($leavelist->result() as $key){
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$key->emp_id.'</td>
    <td>'.$key->status.'</td>
    <td><a id="a'.$key->emp_id.'" onclick="Approved(a'.$key->emp_id.')" title="Approve" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" success><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></td>
    </tr>';
    }
?> 
</tbody>


<script>
function Approved(butId){


    $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo $this->config->item("index_url")."Admin/ApproveLeave";?>",
          data: { rowid: butId },
          dataType:"text",
          success:function(data){
              alert(data);
          },
          error:function (data){
              alert("failed");
          }
        });

}
</script>
```

Comment: No. I'm getting same error. Its in CONTROLLER. It shows `Undefined index:rowid` in my controller php file

Comment: make a `alert` for `butId` in `Approved()` function to make sure `butId` is actually there

Comment: In html, Is there `id` properly as you want?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting `id` to pass to database.

Comment: I'm talking about this `<a id="a'.$key->emp_id.'" onclick="Approved(this)">`  `id` `attribute`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113138/discussion-between-kirataka-and-poonam).